# Is there a cleaner way than while (1) ... break;?

Tags: java

This application matches two lists of words, one in a dictionary file, one that is generated by the application in a TreeSet. Maybe there are better ways to do this, but it's outside of the scope of this question - the way that we use is to read one line from the file, one line from the TreeSet, compare them and

save if the TreeSet line equals the file line

read a line from the file if the TreeSet line > file line

read a line from the TreeSet if the file line > TreeSet line

In pseudo code:

```
while (1) {
    String dict = reader.readLine();
    if (dict == null || !TreeIterator.hasNext()) break;
    if (dict.equals(TreeIterator.next())...save
    elseif > .... read tree
    elseif < .... read file
}
```

It doesn't seem correct to use while (1), but I didn't find a cleaner way to express this double condition.
There is no way to read the two strings inside the while's condition, is there?
Is it possible to maintain the simplicity of this approach (no more clutter), while losing the strange while(1)?

Best regards.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Firstly, `while(1)` is invalid in Java. You'd need `while(true)`. Personally I tend to handle this as:

```
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && TreeIterator.hasNext())
{
    ...
}
```

Although I don't normally like side-effects in conditions, this "get the next one and check it actually exists" approach is sufficiently common that the normal readability pains aren't a problem IME.

Comment: Ok, thank you - this is exactly what I was looking for, but I wasn't sure at all about the (line = reader.readLine()) != null) idiom. Thanks a lot!

Comment: since this is the accepted answer. Using `for` loop has the benefit of limiting the scope of line which is always good and neat.

Answer (score 7):

You can write

```
for(String dict; TreeIterator.hasNext() && (dict=reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
    if (dict.equals(TreeIterator.next())...save
    elseif > .... read tree
    elseif < .... read file
}
```

I am not sure this is any cleaner.

Comment: +1 this has the advantage that the `dict` variable doesn't leak into the outer scope.

Comment: using `delcared... while(declared)` is lame indeed, 'for` loops all the way, they can be extra crafty. Also no one else noticed: `iterator.hasNext()` should precede `readLine()` to avoid potential unneeded IO :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Try

```
String dict;
while ( (dict = reader.readLine()) != null && TreeIterator.hasNext() )
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this (in pseudocode):

```
String dict = reader.readLine();
while (dict != null && TreeIterator.hasNext()) {
    if (dict.equals(TreeIterator.next())...save
    elseif > .... read tree
    elseif < .... read file
    dict = reader.readLine();
}
```

Comment: That will ignore the first line of `dict`, as you're calling `readLine` twice.

Comment: @JonSkeet fixed, thanks. I forgot to delete the first readLine() inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the while with your break conditions:

```
String dict;
while((dict = reader.readLine()) != null && TreeIterator.hasNext())
```

This way the stop conditions is a lot more readable

Comment: Won't ever enter the loop because `dict` hasn't been initialized, if that's a literal straight replace.

Comment: That doesn't cover it, you need the initial `dict = reader.readLine();` before you compare `dict` against `null`.

Comment: `dict` should be initialized before entering the loop. Still incorrect.